# Counter-intuitive effect of reinterpret_cast<T>

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast

I have the  following code :

```
std::vector<short> vec{ 0, 2, 0, 4 };
int* lpvec = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&vec[0]);
```

(Compiled under VC12: short 2 bytes, int 4 bytes)
I think it will produce:

```
lpvec[0] = 2, 
lpvec[1] = 4
```

but it surprises me and outputs

```
lpvec[0] = 2 * 2^16 + 0 = 131072, 
lpvec[1] = 4 * 2^16 + 0 = 262144
```

I said counter-intuitive, because I think vector of shorts lay out in memory in the following pattern:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| 2 bytes | 2 bytes | 2 bytes | 2 bytes |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|       0 |       2 |       0 |       4 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

so, *int* will look the same, but occupies twice as much space:

```
+-------------+------------+
|   4 bytes   |  4 bytes   |
+-------------+------------+
| 0*2^16 + 2  | 0*2^16 + 4 |
+-------------+------------+
```

Would anyone enlighten my why am I wrong?

Comment: You're thinking big endian. Your machine isn't.

Comment: Look up the difference between _little endian_ and _big endian_.

Comment: Well, this invites the question of what's the connection between your problem and Augusta Ada. No, not her pointy head, but rather her maths tutor August de Morgan, who composed a now infamous poem about various sizes of fleas, based on earlier poem by Jonathan Swift who, as you will recall, wrote "Gulliver's travels". In which Gulliver asked the pointed question of why the Lilliputians were called Lilliputians.

Comment: Well, expect _counter intuitive_ behavior from `reinterpret_cast<>()` unless you're exactly know what you're actually doing ...

Comment: On what do you base your intuition on how your system lays out multi-byte integers in memory?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf To cite Sheldon Cooper: _"Greece, a warm summer night 2000 years ago ..."_ ;) ...

Comment: @DavidSchwartz on common sense but it turn out not to be reasonable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Oh noes, that's not cool...**

What you are doing is invoking *undefined behavior*.

Casting an `short*` to `int*` would violate the aliasing rules, but primarily the "unexpected" result is due to the implementation defined [*endianness*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of integral values.

---

**Little- vs Big-endian**

*"Endianness"* is the order of the bytes (representing the value) stored inside an integral type, in this case an `int`.

It seems that your platform is using *little-endian*; meaning that the *least significant byte* is stored first, while your expected result depends on the implementation using *big-endian*; which, as stated, isn't the case.

---

Your implementation stores `short { 2 }` as `[0x02][0x00]`, which would make the `int` pointed to by `lpvec` equivalent to `[0x00][0x00][0x02][0x00]`.

The calculations involved, since your platform uses *big-endian* would be:

```
(2^0 * 0) + (2^8 * 0) + (2^16 * 2) + (2^24 * 0) = 131072
```

<sup>**Note**: the above assumes that a byte is `8` bits wide, something which is also implementation defined.</sup>